# Create a csv file after the first time user logs in

Tags: django

Is there any way of checking when a user logs in for the first time and then create a file? A csv file will be generated using pandas and stored on AWS S3.

User login is done using the django-all-auth library.

Pseudocode:

```
if first_time_login == True:
    create_some_file
```

Focus of the question: How to identify the first login event?

Answer (score 0):

There are many questions you should resolve:

1. How to identify first login of a user?
2. How to generate a CSV file?
3. Where to store that CSV file?

Do you have any thoughts?

---

**UPDATE**

How about to:

1. Extend your User model with `last_login_datetime` field
2. Process [allauth.account.signals.user_logged_in](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/signals.html) signal

The field declaration might be like the following:

```py
last_login_datetime = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

Comment: I will be generating a csv file using pandas and store it on AWS S3. The more pertinent question is how to identify the first login. If this is not possible, then I can do a try/except method where if a target file is not found, I can create one. But where should I check for the event where the user actually logs in? I'm using the django-all-auth library.

Comment: Ok good, could you update the original question with that information?

Comment: I've updated the question. How do I go about extending my User model? Django newbie here :|